# Disable the button if data on its click is not present. This should happen on document ready

Tags: jquery, html

I have simple problem, where I am trying to get a jQuery button to be disabled upon page load

```
<body>    
    <div id="inDetialContainer" style="display:none;">
       <div id="detailText">Detailed Information</div> 
         <button id="overviewDiv" class="nesteIndtText" href="#"   onClick="loadInnerOfChildPage(1);">Overview</button>    // this button should be disabled when data does not exist  
         <button id="proceduresDiv" class="nesteIndtText" href="#" onClick="loadInnerOfChildPage(2);">Procedures</button> // this button should be disabled when data does not exist  
         <button id="equipmentDiv" class="nesteIndtText" href="#" onClick="loadInnerOfChildPage(3);">Equipment</button>   // this button should be disabled when data does not exist  
         <button id="backgroundDiv" class="nesteIndtText" href="#" onClick="loadInnerOfChildPage(4);">Background</button>  // this button should be disabled when data does not exist  
         <button id="safetyDiv" class="nesteIndtText" href="#" onClick="loadInnerOfChildPage(5);">Safety</button>   // this button should be disabled when data does not exist  
         <button id="examQuestionsDiv" class="nesteIndtText" href="#" onClick="loadInnerOfChildPage(6);">Exam Questions</button>    // this button should be disabled when data does not exist  
   </div>         
    <div id="subContent3" style="display:none;">    
      <div id="normalTextHeader">Equipment Details</div>
          <p class="noData">Content not available.</p>
    </div>
      <script>

      $(document).ready(function()
        {
          parent.parent.loadInnerOfChildPage = loadInner; 
         function loadInner(arg)
        {

        var flag = false;
            var parentId;
        flag = ( $("#subContent"+arg).children('p').hasClass('noData'));

            if(flag == false)
            {
              $("#subContent"+arg).css("display","block");  
              $("#subContent"+arg).siblings(this).css("display","none");
              $("#backToNav").css("display","block");   
              }
             else
              {
             parent.parent.$("#inDetialContainer button #").parent().attr("disabled","disabled"); 
             $("#subContent"+arg).css("display","none");
             $("#subContent"+arg).siblings(this).css("display","none");
             $("#backToNav").css("display","none"); 
                }
             }  
     });
   </script>
```

When the page is loaded the click should be disabled on document ready if data is not present. Can anyone explain how is possible?

Thanks!

Comment: So those onclick functions do some ajax requests I assume? If you're running some server side language this would be much more efficient as you can see which ones have child data and then disable them, the only way to do it onload is to fire off lots of ajax requests, see which ones have data, and then disable the buttons if no data is returned.

Comment: You're using jQuery, so why not remove the `onClick` attribute of each button and add an event listener for them in the javascript instead.

Comment: **$("#buttonId").attr("disabled",true);**  when there is no data.. else
enable the button.

Answer (score 0):

All buttons with a `p` child having a class of `noData` are clickable, while those who doesn't will be disabled, right?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nesteIndtText").filter(function() {
    return $(this).children("p.noData").length == 0;
  }).prop("disabled", true);

  $(".nesteIndtText").click(function() {
    // do something when a clickable button is clicked
  });
});
```

The `.filter()` function as used above will return the buttons that doesn't have a `p.noData` in its children, and then they are disabled using `.prop()`.

And I see that you're passing a parameter when a button is clicked, which may be the reason why you're using the `onClick` attributes. This can be done this way instead:

```
<button id="overviewDiv" class="nesteIndtText" href="#" data-arg="1">Overview</button>
<button id="proceduresDiv" class="nesteIndtText" href="#" data-arg="2">Procedures</button>
```

As you can see I added a new attribute, `data-arg`. When a button is clicked, this value can be obtained using `$(this).attr("data-arg")` inside the `click` handler.

Comment: All buttons with a p child having a class of noData are not clickable, while those without class noData will be clickable.

Comment: @Chandni Oh I got it the other way around. Just change the `.filter()` function to `return $(this).children("p.noData").length > 0`, which returns those buttons with a `p.noData` child and then disable them :)